# Importing VMware disk image to Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am trying to move off Rackspace to Google Cloud. I used the VMware converter to take an image of Rackspace and import it into our VMware environment and am trying to import that VMDK into Google Cloud.  However, I am getting the follow error:

```
[translate.translate-disk.wait-for-translator]: 2024-01-05T17:25:57Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-translator-translate-translate-disk-98jjh": StatusMatch found: "TranslateStatus: /dev/sda"
[translate.translate-disk.wait-for-translator]: 2024-01-05T17:26:27Z WaitForInstancesSignal: Instance "inst-translator-translate-translate-disk-98jjh": StatusMatch found: "TranslateStatus: W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://agentrepo.drivesrvr.com/debian serveragent InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 0B37ECD7428661FA Rackspace Cloud Backup (Debian Signing Key 2018-05-21) <cloudbackup@rackspace.com>"
```

In /etc/apt/sources.list all of the Rackspace repos are commented out and the default Ubuntu ones uncommented. Does anyone know how to fix these errors and more importantly, do it without requiring me to upload an entirely new image to Google?

Also why does it care about the repositories on the image just doing an import?

Comment: The error is not about package repositories. Your image has secure boot enabled which will prevent you from moving the image to a different machine. https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?  This server was running in the Rackspace cloud and I used VMware converter to transfer and boot the system in our VMware environment.  The image boots and works locally in VMware so I took that VMDK and uploaded it to GCP where I receive that error.  When I check if secure boot is enabled within VMware, it is not enabled. UEFI is not even enabled, it's booting using legacy BIOS.  If it's booting in legacy BIOS how can it be a secure boot issue?  Could it be something leftover from the Rackspace image and if so would you know how to remove it?

Comment: You have asked some good questions and I don't know the answers. I can just tell you what the error indicates. Your question does not have the details to know what the solution is. When I have similar problems, I restore the image to a local virtual machine so that I can debug the boot process.